# Group by inner array element after $unwind

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following time series data stored in mongodb

```
 { 
   "_id" : ObjectId("59a46062e1aeb958a712490e"),
   "channelName" : "ABC", 
   "rtData" : [ 
   { 
      "ts" : ISODate("2017-08-28T18:26:42.837Z"), 
      "data" : [ 676.297664, 676.297664 ] 
   },
   { 
      "ts" : ISODate("2017-08-28T18:27:42.837Z"), 
      "data" : [ 724.297664, 676.297664 ] 
   },
   { 
      "ts" : ISODate("2017-08-28T18:29:42.837Z"), 
      "data" : [ 878.297, 676.297 ] 
   } 
  ]
 }
```

I want to group the data based on the ts field on hour and get the first element of rtData for that hour.
Here is what I have tried

```
db.channels.aggregate( [ {$match: {"channelName": "ABC"} }, { $unwind : "$rtData" }, { $group : {_id: { $hour: "$rtData.ts" }, ucast: { $sum: $rtData.data[0]} }
```

But the above code gives me the following output

```
{ "_id" : 28, "ucast" : 0 }
```

What I actually want is

```
{ "_id" : 28, "ucast" : 676.297664 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't notate getting a first element of an array in an aggregation pipeline like that. You want [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) which returns the array value by index:

```
db.channels.aggregate( [
  { $match: {"channelName": "ABC"} },
  { $unwind : "$rtData" },
  { $group : {
    _id: { $hour: "$rtData.ts" }, 
    ucast: { $sum: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$rtData.data", 0 ] } }
  }}
])
```

If your MongoDB does not support [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) ( prior to 3.2 ), then you can instead use [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) in an additional [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on just the document key, done before you "accumulate" for the desired grouping key:

```
db.channels.aggregate( [
  { $match: {"channelName": "ABC"} },
  { $unwind : "$rtData" },
  { $group: { 
    _id: { _id: "$_id", ts: "$rtData.ts" },
    data: { $first: "$rtData.data" }
  }},
  { $group : {
    _id: { $hour: "$_id.ts" }, 
    ucast: { $sum: "$data" }
  }}
])
```

In modern versions you can "double barrel" the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to both add up array elements as well as act as an accumulator if you wanted to "sum" **all** elements of the array:

```
db.channels.aggregate( [
  { $match: {"channelName": "ABC"} },
  { $unwind : "$rtData" },
  { $group : {
    _id: { $hour: "$rtData.ts" }, 
    ucast: { $sum: { $sum: "$rtData.data" } }
  }}
])
```

And with older versions ( prior to 3.2 ) you would "double" [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) for each array path instead:

```
db.channels.aggregate( [
  { $match: {"channelName": "ABC"} },
  { $unwind : "$rtData" },
  { $unwind : "$rtData.data" },
  { $group : {
    _id: { $hour: "$rtData.ts" }, 
    ucast: { $sum: "$rtData.data" }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use $first operator for that instead of $sum

```
db.channels.aggregate( [ {$match: {"channelName": "ABC"} }, { $unwind : "$rtData" }, { $group : {_id: { $hour: "$rtData.ts" }, ucast: { $first: $rtData.data} }
```

which will give you output like { "_id" : 28, "ucast" :  [ 676.297664, 676.297664 ]  }

if you want output like { "_id" : 28, "ucast" : 676.297664 } in next $project or $addFields stage use $arrayElemAt